# simple html syntax errors encountered by microsoft webmatrix

Tags: html

I'm using microsoft webmatrix to compile my entire html codes to find bugs.
It showed some status like
 1.**center** tag cannot be nested inside **div** tag 
2.using **span** inside **ul** tag is syntax error and so on..
But my browser displays the output as what I expected .
 Does it matter to consider all these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<center>` tag is deprecated. [(source)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

`<ul>` tag can only have `<li>` and `<ol>` tags as children. [(source)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

> **Permitted content** zero or more `<li>` elements, eventually mixed with `<ol>` and `<ul>` elements.

Your browser renders everything ok, because this is not a syntax error, it's a semantic error. Probably webmatrix is trying to make people write proper HTML.

Comment: Thank you, but surely I need to change some particular text color in <li></li> tags .. that's why I found, using <span> inside <li> tag is the only way ..do you know some alternatives please.

Comment: @MariSelvan what is your doctype? What version of HTML are you validating?

Comment: @MariSelvan <span> inside <li> is OK. However, the message in your question said <span> inside <ul>, which _is_ an error.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova While the MDN page does say "eventually mixed with <ol> and <ul> elements", I'm not sure where they got that. The [W3C page on ul](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) says no such thing, and neither does the [WHATWG page](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-ul-element)

Comment: @MrLister What the MDN page is trying to say is that a `<ul>` can have `<li>` elements **which** can have `<ul>` and `<ol>` inside. **Offtopic**: Look at you rep count, it's almost 22 222 `^^'`

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Sure, but  an <li> can have _anything_ inside, not just lists!

Comment: @MrLister, I have linked info about `<ul>`, not `li`. Because the OP's error stated that he has not permitted content in ul.